# Nature of C Complex numbers data type

Tags: c

I did research trying to visualise how complex number in <complex.h> are stored in RAM. I know for integers, floating points but not for complex. Is it just 2 number like in complex struct ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/complex-h-header-file-in-c-with-examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout is specified in C11 6.2.5/13:

> Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array
> type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is
> equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex
> number.